# How do I test GPS applications using j2me?

Tags: testing, java-me, gps

I need to implement a GPS application for tracking purposes using J2ME...
I wanted to know if there are GPS emulators available for testing the apps??
Are there any other alternative solutions other than using a GPS device for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple program that 'acts' as a GPS device by feeding in predefined GPS coordinates. This will give you full control on what, how and when are GPS coordinates fed to your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you search for "GPS emulator", you get plenty of results.

I can recommend [Franson GPS Gate](http://gpsgate.com/products/gpsgate_client).  I've used it while developing many GPS apps.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own wrapper for the GPS API, and write code to swap in either the real API, or your own test harness.  The harness could write hard-coded data, or talk over HTTP to some API that lets you inject co-ordinates in on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

using any of the emulator given in wtk toolkit you can test gps data

create GPS tracking application
create .xml file which contain coordinates data
go to External events, browse the script select .xml file and play it